# "That sounds great" vs "It sounds great"

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference between two sentences?

For example, let's say a friend of mine says:

> - How about going to the movies?

I would say:

> - That sounds great.

or

> - It sounds great.

Which one is better ?

Could anyone tell the differenct to me?

Comment: I would say `that sounds great`.

Answer (score 2):

**"That sounds great"** is better, meaning **"The *idea* of going to the movies with you sounds great to me."**

**"It sounds great"** *usually* refers to something that actually makes a sound, such as a violin or an orchestra.

Comment: "It sounds great" can also be used as the first meaning. For example, in the question "So what do you think of my plan?", "It sounds great!" is the only proper response; "That sounds great" sounds awkward. I can't quite put my finger on what makes the first one sound better, however.

Comment: @user3932000 But why not respond, "It's great!"? Does "It *sounds* great!" imply a doubt about the validity of the plan in the speaker's mind? To my ear, "That sounds great!" is equally proper and perhaps more definitively positive. Nevertheless, I agree with you that "It sounds great!" feels more conversationally natural, although I too do not know why. Thank you for your comment!